# Read editable input values in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following inline editable grid

```
 var lastsel;
$("#mygrid").jqGrid({
        data:JqgridResponse.rows,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames:['DATE', 'SOURCE', 'DEST', 'FROM', 'TO'],
        colModel:[   
                  //1140 width
            {name:'time', index:'time', width:170 ,sortable:false},
            {name:'source', index:'source', width:290,sortable:false,editable:true,editoptions:{size:"33",maxlength:"50"}},
            {name:'dest', index:'dest',  width:290,sortable:false,editable:true,editoptions:{size:"33",maxlength:"50"}},
            {name:'from', index:'from', width:170,sortable:false,editable:true, edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"us:US;gb:GB;fr:FR"}},
            {name:'to', index:'to', width:170,sortable:false,editable:true, edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"us:US;gb:GB;fr:FR"}}
        ],
        multiselect: true,
            rownumbers: false,
        rowNum:10,                                      
        rowList:[10,50,100],                            
        height: "100%",
        autowidth: true,
        pager: '#pager',                                
            viewrecords: true,                              
            sortorder: "desc",
            ondblClickRow: function(id) {           
                if(id && id!==lastsel){
                jQuery('#mygrid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                jQuery('#mygrid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                lastsel=id;
            }
            }

    });
```

And a navigation button and its event

```
$("#mygrid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
        {   caption:"", 
            buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk", 
            onClickButton: updateLocations,
            title:"Update Locations", 
            cursor: "pointer"
        } 
);

function updateLocations(obj, args){
    //how to get the edited data source, dest, from, to ?
}
```

**How could I get the edited input value of "source" and "dest", and selected value of "from" and "to" at updateLocations method?**

I have tried to located the edited row at Firebug, but the input has no values at all! For example for the "source"

```
<td aria-describedby="mygrid_source" title="N-finger" style="" role="gridcell">
<input id="36_source" class="editable" type="text" size="33" maxlength="50" name="sourcespan" role="textbox">
</td>
```

Am i missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`saveRow`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) to save any edits; calling `restoreRow` will only revert the row back to it's previous values.

I do not believe there is a method that will only get your changes, but you could keep track of all of the changed rows using an array with top-level scope. Then you would need to modify `ondblClickRow` to use that array to keep track of each row ID that has been modified. Then in `updateLocations` you can use `getRowData` to get the data for each of these rows, and (for example) save it via a POST to the server.